# jQuery in bllomberg billionaires?

Tags: jquery

just wondering what is the technology used in this website? is it jQuery?

Especially the animated effects when you do the filtering.

http://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires

Thanks!

Comment: Type `typeof jQuery` in the console, if it returns `"function"` then the page has jQuery included. If you need to check the version, type `jQuery.fn.jquery`. And yeah they're using `1.8`

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of jquery and a lot of straight javascript.  If you right click and view the source you can see for yourself.  You can also enter the address for any external javascript files into your browser to view the source for that.